# Wordpress - how to define cities dropdown values

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am working on an existing wordpress website.
Users has field "user-country" (actually, I do not know how this field is created in wordpress, but it works).
In the registration form, user can choose one specific country.
However, now this country list is note defined "anywhere". It is created explicitly in the code:

```
<option value="Afghanistan" <?php if($current_user->user_country == 'Afghanistan') echo 'selected';?>>Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania" <?php if($current_user->user_country == 'Albania') echo 'selected';?>>Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria" <?php if($current_user->user_country == 'Algeria') echo 'selected';?>>Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa" <?php if($current_user->user_country == 'American Samoa') echo 'selected';?>>American Samoa</opt
```

etc.

The client wants to changed this list (from country to city). So i need to add other values. I do not want to write all values in the code. I would like to create some list with these values in wp-admin.

What is the best way to create a predefined values list? And these are not custom fields for posts.

**EDIT:**
I want to store values in DB, so admin can modidfy these values from wp-admin.
Actually, it is not so important whether it is DB or other option like XML. 
I just want this list to appear as dropdown when user is registering and also to wp-admin to modify values of this list.

Also, a question come to my mind - is it a normal practice to store user custom fields like country or city in DB? Or maybe it is ok to define them in code explicitly?

Comment: Where would the data for the list come from?

Comment: are you saying that you want to store the country list in the db?

Comment: I have modified my post. I think I would like to store them in db. Currently I just have a list of cities in word document.

Comment: You might want to ask this over on the [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want the administrator to be able to modify the list, then DB is likely the best option here.

I would do something like this (in WordPress):

```
// put a default (initial) list in the database, if there isn't one there yet
if(!get_option('my_country_list')){

  // store it as a |-delimited string, because WP serializes arrays,
  // and this would be too much here
  $data = 'Albania|Algeria|Disneyland|etc';

  update_option('my_country_list', $data);
}
```

Now, later where you need that list, simply get it from the db:

```
$countries = get_option('my_country_list');

// turn it into an array
$countries = implode('|', $countries);

// generate the select field
$html = '';
foreach($countries as $country){

  $checked = '';

  if($current_user->user_country == $country)
    $checked = 'selected="selected"';

  $html .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s" %2$s> %1$s </option>', $country, $checked);
}

printf('<select> %s </select>', $html);
```

I guess you'll also have some kind of administration form for the options, where the administrator can modify entries from this list. This could be a textarea. When it gets submitted you `update_option()` again (replace new lines with `|`)

Comment: Is not there some build in way in wp-admin to create something like this? I fully understand your suggestion, but it is doesn't seem as built in, so, for example, I need to create my own administration settings in wp-admin (emm, actually I do not know how to do this). Maybe I am dreaming, but why I cannot create something like custom post type with name cities and then use it?

Comment: You can, see their "book" [example in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). Though it would look kind of weird to have an entire section dedicated to cities in your dashboard :)

Comment: Ok. I have just one more question - where to put the code that creates option with values, so that this option would be then accessible in page and other templates.

Comment: inside a function that you hook on the `init` tag, within your plugin or theme